# How to upsert in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have three columns in my table: id, email, and OAuthEmail. When a user, (user1@example.com) signs up with an email I'd like to create a new record if the email is not in the table. If the user previously signed up with OAuthEmail (if OAuthEmail = user1@example.com), I'd like to add user1@example.com to the email column. I have tried the following -

```
INSERT INTO users ("email") 
  VALUES (user1@example.org) 
ON CONFLICT (user."OAuthEmail" = users1@example.org) 
  DO UPDATE SET (users.email = user1@example.org)
WHERE users."OAuthEmail" = user1@example.org;
```

I am getting a syntax error at "=" on the line - ON CONFLICT (users.email = user."OAuthEmail").

Comment: So which column should contain unique values: `email` or `OAuthEmail`? A few records of sample data and desired results would help clarifying your question.

Comment: Email and Oauth email can be the same values.  If a user signs up with an email, then signs up again with a value that is the same OAuthEmail, then the OauthEmail should be added to the column instead of creating a new record.

Answer (score 1):

You have syntax problems

1. The email address has to be enclosed in quotes
2. The `ON CONFLICT` should specify the conflict column or the name of the constraint
3. There should be no `WHERE` clause
4. If you are going to set the `email` to the value that it already has, then change it to `DO NOTHING`

I hope you do have a `UNIQUE` constraint on the `email` column.

Also, You should not use mixed-case identifiers.  That will give you headaches down the road.

```
with do_update as (
  update users
     set email = "OAuthEmail"
    from invars
   where "OAuthEmail" = 'user1@example.org'
     and email is null
)
insert into users (email)
select new_email 
  from invars
on conflict (email) do nothing;
```

Comment: If OAuthEmail is found, I'd like to add the email to the email field.

Comment: @user3291025 I have modified the query to do what you ask.  I am sorry that I did not read it through completely.  This approach requires a `UNIQUE` constraint on the `email` column.

Comment: @GMB When caffeine is gone, switch to bourbon. :-)